# Python3: Make itemgetter sort by string length

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, python-3.x

I am using the line of code below to sort a list of dictionaries by the value of a specific key. The code does perform the desired sorting. However, it it sorting by Alphanumeric order rather than by string-length. How do I change itemgetter's behavior and make it sort by length?

```
sorted(DATABASE, key=itemgetter('SPECIAL_KEY'), reverse=True)
```

NOTE: In th script, itemgetter is imported via "from operator import itemgetter".

EDIT: Below is some sample data that I am trying to to sort.

Unsorted:

```
DATABASE = [
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'LONG STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'SHORT STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'VERY LONG STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'MEDIUM STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
]
```

Desired:

```
DATABASE = [
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'VERY LONG STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'LONG STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'MEDIUM STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
    {'SPECIAL_KEY': 'SHORT STRING', 'VARIOUS':'DATA'},
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a custom function to do it:

```
sorted(DATABASE, key=lambda x: len(x['SPECIAL_KEY']), reverse=True)
```

To sort the list in-place, you need to use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) instead of `sorted` (`sorted` returns a new list):

```
DATABASE.sort(key=lambda x: len(x['SPECIAL_KEY']), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of the data is moved/sorted. No errors generate though.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson, `sorted` does not sort the list in place, but returns a new sorted list. If you want to sort the list in place, use `list.sort`: `DATABASE.sort(key=lambda x: len(x['SPECIAL_KEY']), reverse=True)`

Comment: thanks. This worked. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I always mistake "sort" and "sorted".